# LESS - passing a parameter to a class for use with calc()

Tags: css, less

Here's my LESS:

```
DIV.row1.col2(@left) {
    left: calc(176px + @left);
    top: -45px;
}

#cards.faerie {
    DIV.row1.col2(20px);
}
```

This renders the calculation of `left` as a style associated with `#cards.faerie` rather than the `DIV` inside it. What am I doing wrong?

I'm going off [this example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/less/namespaces_accessors.htm).

ETA: to also add some context, my HTML looks like:

```
<div id="cards" class="faerie" style="height: 257px;">
        <div id="one" class="row1 col1">
        ...
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code as the documentation said

less

```
.DIV{
    .row1{
        .col2(@left) {
    left: calc(176px + @left);
    top: -45px;
}}}

#cards .row1{
    .DIV> .row1 > .col2(20px)
}
```

Is this useful for you ?

Comment: So is the nested syntax required, then? The DIV in question has two classes on it, rather than those being nested elements. (P.S. Updated my question to add my HTML markup)